# Android fragment app errors

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have this calendar app that I am trying to add into a tabs action bar. But when I join all the code together to try and complete the app i get many errors.

> Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

It tells me that I should try and add it into the android manifest but as they are fragments surely you cant add fragments to the android manifest, anyway here is my code...

```
package com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.tab.TabsPagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    /**
     * Tab titles
     */
    private String[] tabTitles = {"Hours List", "Calendar", "Pay"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        /**
         * For adding tabs
         */
        for(String tabs : tabTitles){
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabs).setTabListener(this));
        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

That was my main activity this is the three fragments,

```
package com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.R;
import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.calendar.adapter.CalendarAdapter;
import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.calendar.util.CalendarCollection;

import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

/**
 * Created by Toby on 02/09/2015.
 */
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * The basic variables that you will need for the calendar
     */
    public GregorianCalendar cal_month, cal_month_copy;
    private CalendarAdapter cal_adapter;
    private TextView tv_month;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         * Sets up the basic layout file, we return this later
         */
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);

        cal_month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        cal_month_copy = (GregorianCalendar) cal_month.clone();
        cal_adapter = new CalendarAdapter(getActivity(), cal_month, CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr);

        tv_month = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_month);
        tv_month.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", cal_month));

        ImageButton previous = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ib_prev);

        previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setPreviousMonth();
                refreshCalendar();
            }
        });

        ImageButton next = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Ib_next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setNextMonth();
                refreshCalendar();

            }
        });


        GridView gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gv_calendar);
        gridview.setAdapter(cal_adapter);
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v,position);
                String selectedGridDate = CalendarAdapter.day_string
                        .get(position);

                String[] separatedTime = selectedGridDate.split("-");
                String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*","");
                int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);

                if ((gridvalue > 10) && (position < 8)) {
                    setPreviousMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                } else if ((gridvalue < 7) && (position > 28)) {
                    setNextMonth();
                    refreshCalendar();
                }
                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).setSelected(v,position);


                ((CalendarAdapter) parent.getAdapter()).getPositionList(selectedGridDate, getActivity());
            }

        });

        return rootView;
    }

    protected void setNextMonth() {
        if (cal_month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == cal_month
                .getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            cal_month.set((cal_month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) + 1),
                    cal_month.getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            cal_month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    cal_month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        }

    }

    protected void setPreviousMonth() {
        if (cal_month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == cal_month
                .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
            cal_month.set((cal_month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                    cal_month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
        } else {
            cal_month.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                    cal_month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
        }

    }

    public void refreshCalendar() {
        cal_adapter.refreshDays();
        cal_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        tv_month.setText(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMMM yyyy", cal_month));
    }
}
```

The second fragment

```
package com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.R;
import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.calendar.adapter.AndroidListAdapter;
import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.calendar.util.CalendarCollection;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Toby on 02/09/2015.
 */
public class HoursListFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ListView lv_android;
    private AndroidListAdapter list_adapter;
    private Button btn_calender;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hours, container, false);

        CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr = new ArrayList<CalendarCollection>();
        CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new CalendarCollection("2015-04-01","John Birthday"));
        CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new CalendarCollection("2015-04-04","Client Meeting at 5 p.m."));
        CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new CalendarCollection("2015-04-06","A Small Party at my office"));
        CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new CalendarCollection("2015-05-02","Marriage Anniversary"));
        CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr.add(new CalendarCollection("2015-04-11","Live Event and Concert of sonu"));


        getWidget();

        return rootView;
    }

    public void getWidget(){
        btn_calender = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btn_calender);
        btn_calender.setOnClickListener(this);

        lv_android = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lv_android);
        list_adapter = new AndroidListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, CalendarCollection.date_collection_arr);
        lv_android.setAdapter(list_adapter);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_calender:
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), CalendarFragment.class));

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

And finally the third which I havent actually coded yet,

```
package com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.R;

/**
 * Created by Toby on 02/09/2015.
 */
public class PayFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pay, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here is the android manifest if you needed it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the adapter class for the main activity

```
package com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.tab;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.fragments.CalendarFragment;
import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.fragments.HoursListFragment;
import com.idkstudios.shiftcalculator.fragments.PayFragment;

/**
 * Created by Toby on 02/09/2015.
 */
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        switch(index){
            case 0:
                return new HoursListFragment();
            case 1:
                return new CalendarFragment();
            case 2:
                return new PayFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        /**
         * This value is equal to the number of tabs you have in the bar
         */
        return 3;
    }
}
```

I did think about having a second plan. The three fragments all came from a activity class, so i copied and pasted the code from the activity class into the fragment so that might be where the issue is. I thought about having the original acitivty classes and just start a new intent from the fragment class to the activity class. But then what would the point of the fragment class be then. Im not too sure if this idea would work in the first place.

Any help would be much appreicated. And if you need any more code please let me know and I will happily provide it, whether that is some of the adapters or the xml code.

Thanks Toby.

Comment: Please provide complete stack trace.What Activity is supposedly not being found? Also, provide source code for where you are starting that Activity.

Answer (score 3):

`HoursListFragment.onClick()` has this buggy statement:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), CalendarFragment.class));
```

As you already know, a fragment is not an activity. Did you mean to pass `MainActivity.class` instead of `CalendarFragment.class`?

Comment: Yeah this logic perfect

Comment: This didnt work unfortunaly, I even removes the click and still crashed.

Answer (score 1):

i think problem is your viewpager adapter,
and your MainActivity is better to extend FragmentActivity
because you want to use fragments

then define three fields in MainActivity class like this

```
CalendarFragment calenderFragment = new CalendarFragment ();

HoursListFragment hourListFragment = new HoursListFragment ();

PayFragment payFragment = new PayFragment ();
```

and one integer as NUMBER_OF_VIEWPAGER_PAGES
or shorter variable name like NUM_PAGE

```
public static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;
```

and make an adapter to your view pager , like this

```
private class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return tabTitles[0] ;
                case 1:
                    return tabTitles[1] ;
                default:
                    return tabTitles[2] ;
            }

        }


        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return calenderFragment;
                case 1:
                    return hourListFragment;
                case 2:
                    return payFragment;
                default:
                    return null;
            }

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
}
```

finally set adapter to your viewPager

```
viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Comment: Sorry I alread have a adapter class, I have edidted the main post now. Sorry